# Box tipping over step with momentum

Tags: torque

Imagine a box on a flat, frictionless plane traveling in a single direction with momentum mv.  Now imagine a step in the plane.  When the box hits the step, it will either stop completely or it will roll over the edge and keep moving.

How do I know which will happen for a given height of box, height of step, mass/velocity of box?

I know this is a torque question.  The variables I am sure are important are:

[(height of center of mass of box) - (height of step)]

[momentum]

[horizontal distance between step and box center of gravity]

[Cosine of the angle between the side of the box and the step] (this term simplifies to 0 for a square box and 90 degree step)

I've also concluded that a unified equation for this simplifies to that of a ball rolling up a frictionless incline (i.e., when the step height approaches 0, and the side-to-step angle approaches 90).  Mostly though, I think I've just forgotten how to set up force diagrams when momentum is involved, so that would be appreciated.

[image]

Edit1: The ol' college try.  I imagine the only relevant force is a torque vector in the opposite direction of the movement of the box, at the position of the top of the step.  This force is arbitrarily high since I can say the box decelerates "near instantly".  Such a force induces a rotation (here, clockwise) on the box about its center of mass.  Where I fail with this treatment is that for any height of the step below the center of mass, the apparent torque appears and should rotate the box.  Of course, this doesn't quite match reality where a sufficiently high step would prevent rotation.

Comment: Why are you so sure the box will either stop or roll-over? It can also recoil or get launched into higher height. First, you need to make sure we know what the question is. Do we assume perfectly elastic collision or not? In reality, collisions aren't completely elastic, but such collisions are harder to analyze so you may start with the perfectly elastic case first. Then mechanical energy is conserved. You should try to analyze what can happen under that assumption on your own and if you get stuck, ask a conceptual question about the point where you are stuck.

Comment: @JánLalinský thanks for the reply.  I can see how the box could recoil backward- in fact, if it hits the step and doesn't rotate, it will surely recoil a small amount.  I'm lumping that case into a general "won't rotate".  That said, I don't see how it could hop up without rotating.... nothing seems to be able to provide a force vector up.  Elastic vs inelastic treatment is irrelevant to me here: I care more about the organization of terms than whether I need to account for some lost energy at the end. Thank you all!

Comment: If the step height is less than half the box height as is the case in the picture, the following is true. In general it *will* rotate after it recoils. It can recoil backward or forward, depending on details. It will always go up. The upward force is provided by the step! You need to do some experiments!